# JQuery Ajax POST - Request Body not showing up in Raw HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, http, request

I have a REST service API that I am trying to access from Javascript that includes GET and POST HTTP requests, and I am having difficulty getting the POST commands to word from Javascript that contain a Request Body.

I can use Fiddler to generate POST requests and get a valid response, but I cannot figure out how to write code similar in Javascript.

An example of a Fiddler request would be something like:

```
http://api.mydomain.com/xml/accounts/authenticate?api_key=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
Request Header:
Host: api.mydomain.com
content-type: text/xml
Content-Length: 123

Request Body:
<Authentication xmlns="http://schemas.mydomain.com/authentication">
 <Firstname>Joe</Firstname>
 <Lastname>Blow</Lastname>
</Authentication>
```

When I execute this, Fiddler shows the follow Raw data:

```
POST http://api.mydomain.com/xml/accounts/authenticate?api_key=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mydomain.com
content-type: text/xml
Content-Length: 143

<Authentication xmlns="http://schemas.mydomain.com/authentication">
 <Firstname>Joe</Firstname>
 <Lastname>Blow</Lastname>
</Authentication>
```

Here is my best attempt at a Jquery Ajax call to do that same call.

```
function accessArctos() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.mydomain.com/xml/accounts/authenticate?api_key=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012',
    type:"POST",
    data: '<Authentication xmlns="http://schemas.mydomain.com/authentication"><Firstname>Joe</Firstname><Lastname>Blow</Lastname></Authentication>',
    error: function() { alert("No data found."); },
    contentType: "text/xml",
    success: function (response) {
        alert('Success Auth Token:' + response);
    }
});
}
```

When I execute this code, Fiddler shows Raw data as this:

```
OPTIONS http://api.mydomain.com/xml/accounts/authenticate?api_key=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mydomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:52381
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I am not sure why the Request body does not show up. I don't know if a Jquery ajax call is the best method to handle this type of Request. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: One problem I found was that on the server side, it was not handling the OPTIONS request that was being sent first before the POST.

I added to my global.aspx on the ASP.NET Server an Application_BeginRequest() method.

It fails now on the POST, but there is an XML record showing up in my Fiddler Raw data as a Request Body. I will continue debugging, but seems I at least got past my initial question.

Comment: protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") {
//headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();}}

Answer (score 0):

Look at the responseText

```
success: function (response, status, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    alert('Success Auth Token:' + response);
}
```

You will probably see the correct text there, but the responseXml will be null since the document is not valid.

Why? Because you are missing the line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

which will make it a valid XML doc

Comment: I added the <?xml to the string, and still get the same response. data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><Authentication xmlns="http://schemas.mydomain.com/authentication"><Firstname>Joe</Firstname><Lastname>Blow</Lastname></Authentication>'.  My request returns a 405 Unauthorized, since it seems no Body is being sent, and gets into the Error.

Comment: So a 405 means you have something wrong with the serverside of things.